# percentage variation pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I  a this data frame code:

```
analytics = q1.groupby(['Year','YearMonth','glnumber','nom'])[['amount']].sum().reset_index()
#add previous sales to the next row
analytics['prev_$'] = analytics['amount'].shift(1)
#drop the null values and calculate the difference
analytics = analytics.dropna()
analytics['diff'] = (analytics['amount'] - analytics['prev_$'])
analytics = analytics.drop(['prev_$'],
  axis='columns')
```

I'm trying to calculate percentage of variation by dividing analytics['prev_$'] by analytics['amount']

this is my code:

```
analytics['Perc_diff'] = analytics.apply(0 if analytics['amount'] == 0 else divide(analytics['diff'], analytics['amount']))
```

But I've this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use np.where for this:

```
import numpy as np
analytics['Perc_diff'] = np.where(analytics['amount']==0,0,analytics['diff']/analytics['amount'])
```